# Problems with the Iterator throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, iterator, try-catch

I am trying to write a program that randomizes groups of people. I am experiencing problems with the Iterator.
Here is the code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void results(List<String> nameslist) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int groups = 0;
    int count = nameslist.size();
    int done=0; 

    do{
        System.out.println("How many people do you want per group?");
        groups = scan.nextInt();
    } while(groups == 0);
    Iterator itr = nameslist.listIterator();
    int peopledone=0;
    while(peopledone<count){    
    int groupsdone = 0;
    while (groupsdone <= groups){
        groupsdone++;
        peopledone = 0;
        System.out.println("Group "+groupsdone+":");
        while (peopledone <= groups){
            try{
                Object obj = itr.next();
                System.out.println(obj);
                peopledone++;
            }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
                Thread.currentThread().stop();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

A few things to note:

- nameslist is a list of letters (a-f) that I put together for testing purposes. Normally, they would be names of people in a class.
- I am trying to get it to just list off names until it runs out.

Thanks so much!

Comment: NoSuchElementException - iteration has no more elements. You should check it.hasNext() before you try and get the next element.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting the NoSuchElementException because, due to the nested loops, you are doing too many iterations.  Once you reach the end of the list, if you call next() on the iterator again, it throws that exception.

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, this should work (there's probably a more elegant way but it at least corrects your issue):

```
public static void results(List<String> namesList)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int namesPerGroup = 0;
        while (namesPerGroup == 0)
            namesPerGroup = scan.nextInt();

        int group = 0;
        int namesInGroup = 0;
        System.out.println("Group " + group + ": ");
        for (String name : namesList)
        {
            if (namesInGroup == namesPerGroup)
            {
                group++;
                namesInGroup = 0;
                System.out.println("Group " + group + ": ");
            }
            System.out.println(name);
            namesInGroup++;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating more times than there are list elements - be sure how many times your loop is going to loop.

What you are trying to do could and should be done in two lines:

```
    Collections.shuffle(nameslist);
    List<String> result = nameslist.subList(0, Math.min(count, nameslist.size()));
```